# Mvc 5 Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I am trying to use the build-in attribute routing that comes with [Mvc 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started), previously I was using the `AttributeRouting` package on Nuget.

But how do i set up routes by specifying whether it is for a Get or Post request?

In `AttributeRouting` there was `GET()` and `POST()` attributes, but in [Mvc 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started) there is only a `Route()` Attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the `Post`Attribute in MVC5, it's fully supported.

> "The earlier style of routing, called convention-based routing, is
>   still fully supported. In fact, you can combine both techniques in the
>   same project."

[source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

Comment: Great, so when binding the routes it will look for whether the Get or Post attributes are also applied and use them when registering the Route?

Comment: Perfect, I assume you mean the HttpPost and HttpGet Attributes - thanks :)